# How to reference field in Gradle plugin class?

Tags: gradle

I'm using a custom Gradle plugin with a class defined like:

```
class CustomPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
  public static final String CONSTANT = 'value'
}
```

I've tried all combinations of `apply plugin: 'platform-java8-fix'` and `import netflix.nebula.platformjava8fix.PlatformJava8FixPlugin` but none of them allow me to reference `CustomPlugin.CONSTANT`.

I would like to do something like:

```
dependencies {
  compile "group:module:${CustomPlugin.CONSTANT}"
}
```

How can this be done?

UPDATE: From within `build.gradle`, I'm able to access `CustomPlugin.CONSTANT`. I would like to access it from another file, `dependencies.gradle`, and have `build.gradle` do:

```
apply from: "${rootDir}/dependencies.gradle"
```

But when I try to perform the `import`, I get the error:

> startup failed:
>         script 'dependencies.gradle': 1: unable to resolve class com.example.CustomPlugin

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  Where in the build script would you reference this constant, and for what purpose?

Comment: The constant is a version of a library that should be consistent. The plugin takes care of that for certain libraries in the 'family' (jersey) but not all of them (eg jersey-multicore).

Comment: Again, where in the build script would you reference this constant, and how?  Is it in your dependency GAVs, or in the body of a custom task, or what?

Comment: It's so I can specify the version of the libraries that's not covered by the plugin (eg jersey-multicore) and also force the versions used by transitive dependencies.

Comment: @NoelYap, could you please provide a runnable example with your failing attempt?

Comment: I've updated the question with sample code showing how I would like to use the constant.